# Dealloc method not being called in dismissModelViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

My modal view controller is not calling its dealloc method when it dismisses itself. I have presented it using :

```
ViewController * vl = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];  
self.viewLink = vl;

[mainMenu stop];
[mainMenu setCurrentTime:0.0];

[vl release];

[self presentModalViewController:viewLink animated:NO];
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks,

Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `viewLink` is a `@property(retain)`, it isn't being deallocated because that object is retaining the modal view controller.

Comment: Thanks. So I should release viewLink when I return from my modal view controller ? What is the best way to do that - should I do [self release] in the modal view controller ?

Comment: @Ohnomycoco: You should set `viewLink` to `nil` when you're done with it.

Comment: Thanks. How can I time time self.viewLink = nil to fire when the modalviewcontroller is dismissed ?

Answer (score 2):

You may not really need to set `viewLink` because when you present a modal view controller a reference to it will be stored in `self.modalViewController`. This will automatically get set to `nil` once you dismiss the controller and the dismissal animation has finished.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried setting to the following an it now crashes   viewLink = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]; 
 
 [mainMenu stop];
 [mainMenu setCurrentTime:0.0];
 
 [viewLink release];
 
 [self presentModalViewController:viewLink animated:NO];

Comment: Eeeeh don't you think you should release viewLink AFTER you call presentModalViewController? ;-) Now you release it before it's used!